# How to break existing node(having data in database) form into multiple steps?

Tags: nodes, forms

I know this type of question is asked earlier also. But with me, situation is somewhat different. I have a node form with many elements. Earlier it was in a single page to create/edit the same. And like that only, we have created the node too. So, data for the node is also there in the database.

Now, I have to split the node into multiple steps(say two steps). I checked and found msnf(drupal community module) is the solution. But that works while creation of the content type only. It will not appear for the existing fields.
So, how can I achieve that?